# Swift project uses Objective-C function

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have limited knowledge about Objective-C and am now learning Swift for iOS development. In a simple iOS app I am writing, I have UIKit imported and found that I can call UIViewController function `present(_:animated:completion:)`. This is reasonable since this is a Swift project.

What confuses me is, that I can also use `NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality)` which is an Obj-C function. This `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` Obj-C function has a counterpart in Swift called `func jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> Data?` I found it strange that I can't use `jpegData` function in my Swift project. Weird?

So my question is, how come I can use an Obj-C function in my Swift project and can't use the counterpart Swift function? Am I missing any imports? And in a broader sense, how does Swift code and Obj-C header/library work together. Sorry if this question has been asked on SO, I know so little about Swift that I dont even know what to search for. I am using XCode 9.2 and Swift 4.0.3.

Comment: You can use `jpegData(compressionQuality:)` in Swift. You have to call it on the `UIImage` instance: `let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality:0.8)`

Comment: @vadian I tried and got an error, `Value of type 'UIImage' has no member 'jpegData'`

Comment: It depends on the SDK. `jpegData(compressionQuality:)` is new in Xcode 10 / Swift 4.2 `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_:_:)` is valid in Xcode 9. Please see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624115-jpegdata?changes=latest_minor

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @vadian! This is so dumb for me not to mention the version of XCode and Swift

Comment: Hello again Vadian. After about a month the link you gave no longer shows the API change on top of the page. Do you know how I could turn it back on? Or somewhere I can look up historical UIKit APIs?

Comment: The API changes are only accessible during the Beta phase. They are described in the release notes.